# Syntax error: 002: on assigning values to variables python

Tags: python

Im writing a program for Uni to find all the palindromic primes, i have written out the program already but when i run it, my first input gets an error while trying to assign values to the variable.

please could someone tell me why this is the case!

```
start =input("Enter the start point N:")
starteval= eval(start)
endval = eval(input("Enter the end point M:"))
reverse=""
x=starteval+1
while x<endval:
    reverse+=start[::-1]
    evalreverse=eval(reverse)

    if evalreverse==starteval:
        if starteval==2 or starteval==3:
            print(starteval)
        elif starteval%2==0 or starteval%3==0:
            pass

        i=5
        w=2
        a=0
        while i<=starteval:
            if starteval%i==0:
                break    
            else:
                a=True
                i+=2

        if a==True:
            print (starteval)
        else:
            pass
        x+=x+1
```

the ouput i recieve is

```
"Enter the start point N:200
Enter the end point M:800
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in <module>
    start =input("Enter the start point N:")
Syntax Error: 002: <string>, line 1, pos 3"
```

please and thank you!

Comment: Also, please don't use eval. If you are using Python 2 and you are looking to get integer values for your input, simply cast as `int` and use `raw_input`. e.g. `int(raw_input("enter you value"))`. Or if you are looking to use `float`, then replace `int` with `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of the first 3 lines to use:

`starteval = int(raw_input("Enter the start point N:"))`
`endval = int(raw_input("Enter the end point M:"))`

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 integer literals cannot begin with a zero:

```
>>> i = 002
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    i = 002
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Because you are applying the `eval` function to your string input, Python attempts to parse your input as a valid Python expression, whcih is why you see the error you see.

It would make more sense to use `int(input(...))` to get the integer (though you would still have to handle any exceptions raised when the user types a non-integer into your code). This has the advantage that it *will* accept the input that is causing you trouble in `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small **intParsing function**, that handles simple input parsing for you, then basically **replace every "eval()"** function of your code with intParsing().

Here is your edited code:

```
  def intParsing(input_str):
     str = ""
     # Delete all chars, that are no digits (you could use a regex for that too)
     for char in input_str.strip():
        if char.isdigit():
           str += char
     # Now you only got digits in your string, cast your string to int now
     r = int( str )

     print "result of parsing input_str '", input_str, "': ", r 

     return r

  start =raw_input("Enter the start point N:") 
  starteval= intParsing(start)               # I edited this line
  end = raw_input("Enter the end point M:")  # I edited this line
  endval =intParsing(end)                    # I edited this line

  reverse=""
  x=starteval+1
  while x<endval:
      reverse+=start[::-1]
      evalreverse= intParsing(reverse)      # I edited this line
```

Comment: Or he simply stops using `eval()` but okay. Lets write another function for it...

Comment: Yes, of course he should stop using eval(), but that was already mentioned multiple times.

Comment: Thats why it doesn't make sense for me to create a new procedure